# How to invoke functions or get data in/of a contract from another contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I have a contract that creates instances of a contract and now I have to get the data of the newly created contract. Is there a way to do that?

This is my contract that creates new contracts:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.8;

contract myFirstContract
{
    address[] public childContracts;
    uint public idd;
    string public name1;

    function newContracts(uint _id,string _name) public returns(address _newContract)
    {
        uint id=_id;
        string memory name=_name;
        anotherContract a = new anotherContract(id,name);
        childContracts.push(a);
        return a;
    }

    function getContractData(uint _address) public
    {

    }
}

contract anotherContract
{
    string public name;
    uint  public id;
    constructor(uint _id,string _name) public
    {
        name=_name;
        id=_id;
    }
}
```

Now, let's say that there is a new `anotherContract` getting created and I have the address of this contract then how do I get the data in this new contract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this. You need to define get methods inside your anotherContract. This way I was able to create new anotherContract with method newContracts and later later it data with method getContractData.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.8;

contract myFirstContract
{
    address[] public childContracts;
    uint public idd;
    string public name1;

    function newContracts(uint _id,string _name) public returns(address _newContract)
    {
        uint id=_id;
        string memory name=_name;
        anotherContract a = new anotherContract(id,name);
        childContracts.push(a);
        return a;
    }

    function getContractData(uint _address) public view returns(uint, string)
    {
        anotherContract anotherContractInstance = anotherContract(_address);
        return (anotherContractInstance.getId(), anotherContractInstance.getName());
    }
}

contract anotherContract
{
    string public name;
    uint public id;

    constructor(uint _id,string _name) public
    {
        name=_name;
        id=_id;
    }

    function getId() view public returns(uint) {
        return id;
    }

    function getName() view public returns(string) {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: So in getContractData I was trying to have something like `uint idd = _address.id;` and it wasn't working and this does. Thanks